# Matplotlib's LaTeX run directory

Tags: matplotlib, latex, pgf

Where is the LaTeX run directory for matplotlib? Are the LaTeX log files kept at all?

I use pdflatex system to generate a ".pgf" plot, that I could insert into my LaTeX document. Unfortunately the python traceback shows only a small part of the log file, which is not enough to solve the issue. I would like to take a look at the log file. The traceback tells me the following:

```
! Dimension too large.
<to be read again> 
                   \relax 
l.995 \Gm@process
                 
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on figure.log.

and the following error:


shell returned 1
```

Since I have nowhere "\Gm" in my python code, I would need to take a look at the .tex file and the log to help me figure out what is going on. I've tried to search for the file "figure.log" on my system, but it does not exists.

Comment: there is a bunch of stuff output by latex in `~/.matplotlib/tex.cache`; you could try looking there first?

Comment: @tmdavison Unfortunately I have no such directory. Is there maybe a variable of matplotlib library/package/class, which tells me where this could be?

Comment: try looking here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/faq/troubleshooting_faq.html#locating-matplotlib-config-dir. In short, you could try: `mpl.get_cachedir()`

Comment: Thanks, @tmdavison. I did not know that, and I was trying to search on the internet. There is something really strange there. There is no file there from today, although I've run matplotlib a few times with the pgf backend. I still have to figure it out why.